# Using delegate for async method that creates a form but never completes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a c# asynchronous method that seems to never complete. It is called via a delegate and creates a form. If I eliminate the delegate or the form creation it works fine. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Code as follows:

```
public delegate Task<bool> TaskDel();

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Tag = (TaskDel)taskAsync; 
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if I don't use a delegate here there is no problem.
        await Task.Run(() => ((sender as Button).Tag as TaskDel)());
    }

    public async Task<bool> taskAsync()
    {
        await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(URL);
        Form form = new Form(); // if I remove this line method works.
        await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(URL);
        return true; // as is, never reaches this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Inside your async task, I think no UI action should be performed. Async task is usually for resource hungry, long running process, such as polling a URL for data (as you did here), or a length calculation, deserializing a data file, etc. You cannot interact directly with any UI controls on the calling form.
2. using a delegate is not needed. you may directly call:

   ```
   private async void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(URL);
       Form form = new Form();
   }
   ```

Comment: The code I included was the simplest I could write that manifested the problem. I actually need to use a delegate since the method called is not known at compilation. I really want to understand though why the form creation and delegate use seem to block the execution. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: it is because you are not allowed to call new Form on a thread that is not a UI thread, which is what Task.Run does.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that Task.Run does that. I had been thinking it was equivalent to await which does seem to run on UI thread. And it doesn't seem possible to use await with a delegate. Thanks very much.